# Sorting Integer array using Comparable

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a project in which I *have*  to sort an array of Integer objects by using Comparable.

My add method takes an item of type E. If my size variable (which tracks the elements in my array theData[]) is = 0 (which it is initialized to), I simply put the item in theData[0].

If it is not, I use item.compareTo to compare the item against each item already in the array. If the result of compareTo is < 0 for a number in the array, I shift everything at that number and after to the right, and insert the item before it.

If compareTo returns a 0, meaning the item is equal to the number in the array, I do nothing as I don't want duplicates in the array.

If none of the compareTo statements in the loop return a -1 or a 0, I put the item in theData[size], the end of the array, as it must be larger than all the other numbers.

However, this doesn't work. Any time I make a new Set and add a few numbers to it, then try to print out the contents of my set using a for loop,I keep getting a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 error for this line:

```
theData[j + 1] = theData[j];
```

I've tried starting from scratch and re-writing my loop with different logic, and each time I keep hitting this wall. I know I must either be shifting incorrectly or not increasing the size of the array correctly with my reallocate method, but I can't wrap my head around it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Set<E extends Comparable<E>> {

String s;
String name;
private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;
private E[] theData;
private int size = 0;
private int capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Set() {
    theData = (E[]) new Comparable[capacity];
}

public Set(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void add(E item) {

    if (size == capacity) {
        reallocate();
    }

    if (size == 0) {                        // If size is 0, add item to theData[0]
        theData[size] = item;
        size++;
        return;
    }

    else {                                  // Else compare the item to every item in loop.
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            int result = item.compareTo(theData[i]);

            if (result < 0) {       

                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {        //If item is less than a number, shift everything
                    theData[j + 1] = theData[j];        //after that index to the right, and add item
                    theData[j] = item;

                }
            }

            if (result == 0) {
                return;
            }

            else {                                      //If item is not less than or equal to any
                theData[size] = item;                   //numbers in the array, add it to the end
                size++;

            }

        }

    }

}

/*
 * if (size>=1){ int result = item.compareTo(theData[size-1]); if(result<0){
 * E temp = theData[size-1]; theData[size-1] = item; theData[size] = temp; }
 * if(result>1){ return; } }
 */

public E get(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return theData[index];
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

private void reallocate() {
    capacity = 2 * capacity;
    theData = Arrays.copyOf(theData, capacity);
}

}
```

Edit: The driver method I'm using to test it -

```
public class Driver {

String one = "two";

public static void main(String[] args){

Set<Integer> one = new Set<Integer>();

one.add(63);
one.add(20);
one.add(127);
one.add(10);
one.add(26);
one.add(15);

for(int i = 0; i < one.size(); i++){
System.out.println(one.get(i));
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `j == size - 1`, `theData[j+1]` will take you out of the array.

You want to loop to one before the end instead.

```
 for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {        //If item is less than a number, shift everything
     theData[j + 1] = theData[j];        //after that index to the right, and add item
     theData[j] = item;
}
```

---

So I've also taken a look at the logic you've got for the insertion, and it doesn't make a lick of sense.  Why do you delay the insertion at all?  If you've got the room, *just add it!*

Next, the double loops are essentially implementing [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), but there's a fatal flaw with it:  you don't ever complete the swap; you only overwrite your values repeatedly.  You're also not comparing in the right direction; you want to swap if the value on the left is *larger* than the value on the right, since you're starting from the *beginning* of the array.

So, with that...this is what an implementation would have the form of...

```
public void add(E item) {

    if (size == capacity) {
        reallocate();
    }

    theData[size++] = item;
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
            if (theData[j].compareTo(theData[j + 1]) > 0) {
                // perform the swap (you need an extra variable!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I leave implementing the swap as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I made that change, and now I oddly get nothing but 15 for the output, which is the last number I added to the list (I will add my main method above)

Comment: @sam:  I've revised my answer.  I still feel sound in that I've addressed your original issue; the rest of the issue may be you hashing it out with a tutor or your professor.

Comment: I do greatly appreciate your help. I just don't want to check off an answer yet in case others were going to add something.

Comment: I performed the swap and got it working. Thank you so much, you're right, my logic was a mess and yours is so much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your shift loop, you are inserting the new item in every position instead of shifting then inserting in [i] because you copy theData[j] to the next position, but always assign item to theData[j], is that right? 
Second, you are starting from the beginning of array since j starts with 0. J should start with i.
Third and main bug, you verify if result < 0 then you verify IF result == 0, change for a ELSE IF so the else don't get executed even when result < 0

Comment: I see what you mean with j starting at i, but I'm not sure why the item would be inserted at every position. I am trying to make it so if the compareTo returns -1, everything from theData[j] onward is shifted right, and the item becomes the new theData[j].

Comment: @Sam, You were assigning item to theData[j] every iteration when in fact you wanted to assign item to theData[i] after the shift loop

Answer (score 0):

shift elements to right can be done from right to left, like:

```
for (int j = size; j > i; j--) { // If item is less than a
                                // number, shift
                                // everything
    theData[j] = theData[j - 1]; // after that index to the
                                // right, and add item

}
size++;
theData[i] = item;
break;// after insert the number, we can just break the for loop
```

once the new number is inserted, break the for loop, else, the `size` variable will not be correct

```
else {                    // If item is not less than or equal to any
    theData[size] = item; // numbers in the array, add it to the end
    size++;
    break;
}
```